# Определить порядок числа на JS

Tags: javascript

Есть строка со значениями в JS:

```
var string = '5, 81, 9';
```

Как определить например, какая по счету цифра 81?

Comment: var idx = string.split(/,\s*/, '').indexOf('81');
    if( idx > -1 ){
        alert('pos: '+idx);
    }

Comment: @RubaXa: не стоит искать строку, т.к. исходные данные могут быть `"881, 81, 9"`.

Comment: @VladD, только строку, т.к. string.split(/,\s*/) вернет `String[]`. т.е. `"881, 81, 9".split(/,\s*/) => ["881", "81", "9"]`

Comment: @RubaXa, не работает..

Comment: если вспомнить, что 81 это не цифра, то ответ стает очевидным. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Разбиваем](http://javascript.ru/String/split) строку на отдельные элементы
2. [Находим](http://javascript.ru/String/indexOf) позицию нужного элемента ([не работает](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.indexOf) в IE8 и ниже, что, впрочем, [поправимо](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FindexOf))
3. ...
4. PROFIT!

Comment: Потому что вы ищите 2 (number), а в array_move_split состоит из string.

Comment: Криво однако всё работает.    

    >>var array_move = '1,22,3,2';
    var array_move_split = array_move.split(',');
    var array_move_position = array_move_split.indexOf('2');
    alert(array_move_position);

Выдаёт 3, что за бред?

Comment: Позиция начинается с "0", почитайте про JS.

Comment: @ModaL судя по количеству заданных вами вопросов здесь, вам стыдно не знать, что в большинстве языков программирования нумерация в массивах  начинается с нуля